# T-sql, Query with parent ID

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

[image]

I want to write a query like this: if I choose DictID where DictParentID is NULL (which mean this is parent ID), I want to list all DictID with DictParentID = my DictID(in this case 10240) and also 10240. 
In other case (when I choose DictID when DictParentID is not NULL) I want to list only this DictID.

I have problem with write this query. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simple and efficient, use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT DictiId, DictParentId
FROM dbo.TableName t
WHERE DictId = @DictId

UNION ALL

SELECT DictiId, DictParentId
FROM dbo.TableName t
WHERE DictParentId = @DictId
```

If you want to order it you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT x.DictiId, x.DictParentId FROM
(
    SELECT DictiId, DictParentId
    FROM dbo.TableName t
    WHERE DictId = @DictId

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DictiId, DictParentId
    FROM dbo.TableName t
    WHERE DictParentId = @DictId
) x
ORDER BY x.DictiId, x.DictParentId
```

Comment: great, great. Thanks Man!!

Answer (score 0):

Simple and efficient, use `OR`:

```
SELECT 
   DictiId, DictParentId
FROM 
   dbo.TableName t
WHERE 
   DictId = @DictId OR
   DictParentId = @DictId
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flip our good friend the `in` clause around for good effect here:

```
SELECT DictiId, DictParentId
FROM dbo.TableName t
WHERE @DictId in (DictId, DictParentId);
```